# When export a module. Should we asign the value to a const variable? Is it a good practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Any reason that someone exports a const variable instead of directly export it?

```
export const abc = function Home(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Template {...props} />
    </div>
 );
}
```

usually, I will directly export like this:

```
export function Home(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Template {...props} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

What are the differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is you're exporting `Home` as `abc` in the first case.

I would prefer the second way unless I need to export my function with different name. This is because, when you assign something to a variable, a small bit of memory is reserved for that variable, in this case it's `abc`. And, this becomes an useless variable if you're not reusing it anywhere. So, going with the second option is a good practice.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In the first you have the ability to reference it by name, and have multiple exports in the same file. Also, const provides you the check that it can't be modified later.

Also the 2nd syntax should probably contain a default.

**Edit:**
The first is called using named export abc instead of Home. First can be made shorter using es6.

Comment: Sorry. I just changed the question. But I believe you still can have mutiple export in the same file and when you import the file it's readonly also. What's the point of using the const then...

Comment: Okay now it's just about named call of function, you can call the first one using abc too. Also in the first case you could use Arrow functions for shorter code.